# Applying a method generically to initialize member through a class template's constructor using SFINAE with constructor delegation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, list-initialization

I have this class template that is using SFINAE with constructor delegation. There are 3 cases to determine which version of the constructor(s) that will be called.

> **Overall structure of class:**
>
> - In the first case it is constructing a smaller size from a larger size and can extract a byte, word, or dword from a word, dword or qword by the index value
> - In the second case it is constructing a larger size from a smaller size and
>     can set a byte word or dword into word, dword or qword at that index location.
> - In the third case (default) case it is a 1 to 1 mapping so no calculations nor assertions need to be performed, just save the contents, and the index parameter if passed will have no effect.

---

**Register.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

namespace vpc {
    using u8  = std::uint8_t;
    using u16 = std::uint16_t;
    using u32 = std::uint32_t;
    using u64 = std::uint64_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register {
        T data;
        T value;
        std::bitset<sizeof(T)* CHAR_BIT> bits;

        Register() : data{ 0 }, value{ 0 }, bits{ 0 } {}

        template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) > sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        Register(const P val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            data{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {

            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeP = sizeof(P);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeP / sizeT) - 1)) );
        }    

        template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) < sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        Register(const P val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            data{ /*static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },*/
                static_cast<T>(val)
                },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {
            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeP = sizeof(P);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeT / sizeP) - 1)) );
        }    

        template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) == sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        Register(const P val, const u8 idx = 0) :
                  // shouldn't need the static cast but I'll leave it here for now
            data{ static_cast<T>( val ) }, value{ data }, bits{ data }
        {}

        template<typename P>
        Register(const Register<P>& reg, const u8 idx = 0) : Register(reg.data, idx) {}

    };

    using Reg8  = Register<u8>;
    using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
    using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
    using Reg64 = Register<u64>;

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Register<T>& r) {
        return os << "Reg" << std::size(r.bits) << '(' << r.data << ")\nhex: 0x"
            << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T) * 2) << std::hex
            << r.data << std::dec << "\nbin: "
            << r.bits << "\n\n";
    }

    template<>
    std::ostream& operator<<<u8>(std::ostream& os, const Register<u8>& r) {
        return os << "Reg" << std::size(r.bits) << '(' << +r.data << ")\nhex: 0x"
            << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(u8) * 2) << std::hex
            << +r.data << std::dec << "\nbin: "
            << r.bits << "\n\n";
    }
} // namespace
```

And if we look at the first case where `sizeof(P) > sizeof(T)` where we are using the class's initializer list to initialize it's member `data` The following formula is being done to `data`:

```
data{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                      std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) }
```

And in the second case where `sizeof(P) < sizeof(T)` it is currently commented out.

```
data{ /*static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
      std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },*/
    static_cast<T>(val)
    }
```

What I would like to do is something similar above but I want to generically apply this method to initialize `data` in this case:

```
void insertByte(unsigned char a, unsigned int& value, unsigned idx) {
    if (idx > 3)
        return;

    // clear the value at position idx
    value &= ~(0xFF << (idx * 8));

    unsigned int tmp = a;
    tmp = (tmp << (idx * 8));

    value |= tmp;
}
```

The parameters in the function above `a` and `value` will be the template types: `T` and `P` within my class. The if statement will be handled by the assertion.

This may also help to understand the function above:

```
unsigned a = (the_int & 0x00ffffff) | (the_byte << 24);  // set high-order byte: bits 24-31
unsigned b = (the_int & 0xff00ffff) | (the_byte << 16);  // next byte, bits 16-23
unsigned c = (the_int & 0xffff00ff) | (the_byte << 8);   // next byte, bits 8-15
unsigned d = (the_int & 0xffffff00) | (the_byte);        // low-order byte: bits 0-7
```

Any thoughts on how I could convert the above function to fit my template in order to initialize `data` with the correct values? It is basically the reverse of the first case constructor.

---

---

**Edit**

---

---

Based on a comment from user: [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring) I'm going to illustrate the concept of my second case constructor:

```
Reg8 r8{ 0xAA };

Reg32 r32a{ r8, 0 };
Reg32 r32b{ r8, 1 };
Reg32 r32c{ r8, 2 };
Reg32 r32d{ r8, 3 };
// Reg32 r32{ r8, 4 }; // assertion failure

// binary output in hex notation:
r8   = 0xAA
r32a = 0x000000AA
r32b = 0x0000AA00
r32c = 0x00AA0000
r32d = 0xAA000000

// Another example
Reg16 r16{ 0xABCD };

Reg32 r32a{ r16, 0 };
Reg32 r32b{ r16, 1 };
// Reg32 r32c{ r16, 2 }; // assertion failure 

Reg64 r64a_0{ r32a, 0 };
Reg64 r64a_1{ r32a, 1 };
// Reg64 r64a_2{ r32a, 2 }; // assertion failure

Reg64 r64b_0{ r32b, 0 };
Reg64 r64b_1{ r32b, 1 };
// Reg64 r64b_2{ r32b, 2 }; // assertion failure

Reg64 r64c_0{ r16, 0 };
Reg64 r64c_1{ r16, 1 };
Reg64 r64c_2{ r16, 2 };
Reg64 r64c_3{ r16, 3 };
// Reg64 r64c_4{ r16, 4 }; // assertion failure

// binary output in hex notation:
r16    = 0xABCD
r32a   = 0x0000ABCD
r32b   = 0xABCD0000
r64a_0 = 0x000000000000ABCD
r64a_1 = 0x0000ABCD00000000
r64b_0 = 0x00000000ABCD0000
r64b_1 = 0xABCD000000000000
r64c_0 = 0x000000000000ABCD
r64c_1 = 0x00000000ABCD0000
r64c_2 = 0x0000ABCD00000000
r64c_3 = 0xABCD000000000000
```

This is what I intend from any larger size constructed from smaller size with index value provided if no index then it is always set to the lowest byte from the right.

---

---

**EDIT**

---

---

This is my first attempt at trying to do what I intend to do, and here I'm using a lambda template. I created this lambda and it is in my class's header file above after the using's and before the class declaration within my namespace.

```
template<typename P, typename T>
auto wordSize = [](T& t, P& p, const u8 idx) {
    p &= ~(0xFF << (idx * 8));
    P tmp = static_cast<P>( t );
    tmp = (tmp << (idx * 8));
    p |= tmp;
    return p;
};
```

Now in try to use this in my second case constructor:

```
template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) < sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
explicit Register(P val, const u8 idx = 0) :
    data{ static_cast<T>( wordSize<T,P>(val, data, idx ) ) },
    value{ data },
    bits{ data }
{
    constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
    constexpr u16 sizeP = sizeof(P);
    assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeT / sizeP) - 1)) );
}
```

Except here I had to change the Constructor's parameter for `<P>` from `const <P>` to just `<P>` for this to work. Now when I construct my Register types from smaller types I am inserting the correct word or byte into the right index location, however the rest of the bits are not being `0` initialized.

Example:

```
Reg8    r8{ 0xAA };
Reg32 r32a{ r8, 0 };
Reg32 r32b{ r8, 1 };
Reg32 r32c{ r8, 2 };
Reg32 r32d{ r8, 3 };

// Expected Binary Output in Hex:
r8   = 0xAA
r32a = 0x000000AA
r32b = 0x0000AA00
r32c = 0x00AA0000
r32d = 0xAA000000

// Actual Outputs:
r8   = 0xAA
r32a = 0xCCCCCCAA
r32b = 0xCCCCAACC
r32c = 0xCCAACCCC
r32d = 0xAACCCCCC
```

I'm very close to achieving my goals, but now I just need to adjust this so that all of the `CC` are `00`.

Comment: Should all the bits not set using the smaller input be set to 0?

Comment: @DavisHerring I can append to my question giving you an example of the 2nd case in pseudo code.

Comment: @DavisHerring I updated my question with an edit based on your comment-question above.

Comment: I came up with something close using a lambda template and I am getting the correct values inserted into the right locations, but all of the other values are not `{0}` initialized... I could append that to this question upon request as it is my most current attempt to incorporate the method to initialize my values accordingly.

Comment: Side note: why not use `+` in the primary `operator<<` template so that it works for `char` too?

Comment: @DavisHerring I was having issues when promoting to int for types that weren't u8 so just to specialize it for unsigned char type, it isn't a big deal. Once I get these constructors working, I may try to remove that latter.

Comment: I must be missing something: what’s wrong with `static_cast<T>(val)<<sizeof(P)*CHAR_BIT*idx`?

Comment: @DavisHerring Hmm, I might have to try that, but look at my `lamda` approach; I appended it to the end of this question.

Comment: The 0xCC is a common (but not universal!) “uninitialized memory” indicator.  Just use `<<` and you don’t have to deal with any of it.

Comment: @DavisHerring oh okay, and I tried your implementation, but now I'm getting a compiler error C2397: conversion from `'int'` to `'T'` requires a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @DavisHerring If I get this to work, make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @DavisHerring I took what you said, but it should be like this:  `static_cast<T>(val << sizeof(P)*CHAR_BIT*idx)`

Comment: You want *both* casts, in case `T` is wider than `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly initialize any integer type `T` with a shift from any integral `P val`, use

```
data{static_cast<T>(static_cast<T>(val) << sizeof(P)*CHAR_BIT*idx)}
```

The inner cast is necessary for the shift to be well defined for `T` wider than `int`; the outer one is necessary to counteract promotion for `T` narrower than `int` (or just use parentheses rather than braces to allow the narrowing conversion).